# Mysql query to count data from multiple tables and display 0 for null values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

My tables are:

```
Department(Dept_id,Dept_name#)

Employee(Emp_id#,Emp_Name,Address,Phone,Email,Dept_name)
```

From the above tables to show the following details (`Dept_Id`,`Dept_name`,`Total Employees`).

I use the following query:

```
SELECT dept_id,department.dept_name,count(emp_id)"Total" 
FROM department,employee_details 
WHERE department.dept_name=employee_details.dept_name 
GROUP BY dept_id;
```

In the above query I don't get all `dept_name` rather I get `dept_name` and `dept_id` of whose `emp_id` is counted. So how can I get the all data of `dept_name` and `dept_id` and corresponding result as `0` i.e `Count(emp_id)=0`.

Comment: You need to do left join rather than inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of implicit `INNER JOIN` and add `department.dept_name` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT d.dept_id
     , d.dept_name
     , COUNT(ed.emp_id) AS Total 
FROM department d 
LEFT JOIN employee_details ed ON d.dept_name = ed.dept_name
GROUP BY d.dept_id
       , d.dept_name
```

Comment: But I get the same problem

Comment: @Manoj Warkade : Updated